# Como fazer elemento minimizado ou escondido em site?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Qual o nome para que eu possa pesquisar como faz, daqueles itens no html que aparecem minimizado na pagina. por exemplo:

em um site html na sua home do lado direito perto da barra da janela tem uma imagem cortada que quando vc clica nela ela desliza para a esquerda e mostra ela completa.

Caso nao tenha ficado claro vou procura algum site com isso e posta a imagem.
Obrigado

Comment: Isso aí não é uma [*navbar*](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)? Acho que com a imagem fique mais claro.

Comment: Então, é como o dropdown do nav bar, mas no caso seria a direita da pagina e meio que seria escondido. vou procurar a imagem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar css e jquery, vou da um exemplo aqui, neste exemplo ao clicar na div ela aparece na tela.

Primeiro você "esconde" ela utilizando o css:

```
.janela{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid #f00;
  margin-top: -90px;
  position:fixed;
}
```

E então você mostra utilizando jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $( ".janela" ).click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      marginTop: 0
    }, 1500 );
  });
});
```

Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/9stsct8r/

**Update:**

Desta forma a tela aparece ao clicar e esconde ao clicar novamente, ele verifica a margin-top e realiza a ação:

```
$(function(){
alert($(".janela").css('margin-top'));
  $(".janela").click(function() {
    var pos = parseInt($(this).css('margin-top').replace("px", ""));
        if(pos == 0){
        $(this).animate({
        marginTop: -90
      }, 1500 );
    }else{
      $(this).animate({
        marginTop: 0
      }, 1500 );
    }
  });
});
```

Resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/9stsct8r/1/

Comment: olha só jovem! rsr é isso mesmo que eu queria! valeu

Comment: um codigo pra esconder novamente ficaria como @wictor

Comment: Fiz a alteração com a resposta.

Comment: Valeu mito! um dia eu chego lá rsrs